# How to use the COLLATE in a JOIN in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, join, collate

I´m trying to join two tables but I get this error:

> *Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 8 Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.*

This is the code I´m using:

```
 SELECT *

  FROM [FAEB].[dbo].[ExportaComisiones] AS f

  JOIN [zCredifiel].[dbo].[optPerson] AS p

  ON (p.vTreasuryId = f.RFC) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

I know it is wrong, it underlines **COLLATE**. I do not know how to apply it.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Correct syntax looks like this. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx).

```
SELECT *
  FROM [FAEB].[dbo].[ExportaComisiones] AS f
  JOIN [zCredifiel].[dbo].[optPerson] AS p

  ON p.vTreasuryId COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = f.RFC COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: With SQL Server the general "rule" appears to be `string_expression COLLATE collation_name` to treat the entity with a specific collation.. not sure how general it is, although it's reasonable enough for me to remember.

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule, you can use **Database_Default** collation so you don't need to figure out which one to use. However, I strongly suggest reading Simons Liew's excellent article [Understanding the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT clause in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/)

```
SELECT *
  FROM [FAEB].[dbo].[ExportaComisiones] AS f
  JOIN [zCredifiel].[dbo].[optPerson] AS p
  ON (p.vTreasuryId = f.RFC) COLLATE Database_Default
```