# conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, error-handling

I try to join two tables from different SQL servers. I made a LikndedServer, it takes the data from that server, but when I do '`inner join`' with a table from another Db is shows this error : `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation`

The query is like below:

```
select * from [DB1].[dbo].[Employee] as P1 
inner join [LinkedWebServer].[DB2].[dbo].[View_HyrjeDalje_Punetoret] as P2 on
 P1.[Personal_No] = P2.[vcNumriPersonal]
```

Thank You!

Comment: Hint:  `COLLATE`.

Comment: You have to decide which collation to use in the comparison. This kind of error indicates inconsistent table design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the COLLATE in a JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300955/how-to-use-the-collate-in-a-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from [DB1].[dbo].[Employee] as P1
inner join [LinkedWebServer].[DB2].[dbo].[View_HyrjeDalje_Punetoret] as P2 on
P1.[Personal_No] collate database_default = P2.[vcNumriPersonal] collate database_default